Cursor editor line/word/code bizarre wrapping problems
I'm new to Cursor and love it. But I'm confounded by this:
<a href="blah.html"
          >a web page</a
        > blah blah blah.

If I manually reformat it, on save it will revert it to this monstrosity.
I don't understand enough about Cursor to know why it's doing this or what settings I need to change to stop this behavior. Initially I thought the Prettier component was the culprit but I disabled it and the behavior continued...
I've set word wrapping to 150 but it doesn't seem to matter. Even if I widen the editor window, the above stays intact.
I have several pages of copy like this to edit...
I'm not sure what other info I can provide.
Update: Switching off "Format on Save" in the VSCode/Cursor settings stopped the behavior, so that suggests that whichever "formatter" it's using is the culprit. I don't know if Cursor comes pre-loaded with that or if it's an add-on.
